# Why can't allocate stack memory dynamically in visual c++? but gcc can do it

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, compilation, stack-memory

when I compile the following piece of code with gcc, it work fine and show correct output as I expected, but when it move to windows with visual c++, it report errors when compiling.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fun(int numAttrib)
{
    typedef struct {
        int  attribList[numAttrib];
    }VADataFull;
    printf("size=%ld\n", sizeof(VADataFull));
    return 0;
}

int main(int i, char** args)
{
    fun(i);
    return 0;
}
```

Actually, I can understand why vc++ cannot work, because, as we have learned in shool, we cannot allocate memory dynamically in the stack, but gcc works fine, so I feel confused, could anyone tell me more about this issue, Thanks

Comment: Because GCC implements them [as an extension to the language](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GCC` does not compile Standard C++ by default (for some crazy reason). It allows various non-standard extensions (like your *variable length array*). You have to set switches for standard version and pedantic mode to enforce it:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic-errors -o prog prog.cpp
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a gcc extention to the language.
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html
As can be seen [here](https://godbolt.org/z/ZpDRf1) gcc won't compile it as well when given c++ mode instead of default gnu that allows lots of non standard exstentions to be used.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not Standard C++ that's why it compiled in gcc.

g++ supports a C99 feature that allows dynamically sized arrays.